# PHP Registration Form Not Showing

Tags: php

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

 if($password == $password2){
  if($email == $email2){
   //All good, carry on the registration.
  }else{
   echo "Oh no! We can't sign you up; please double-check your passwords match.<br />";
   exit();
  }
 }else{
  echo "Oh no! We can't sign you up; please double-check your emails match.<br /><br />";
 }


$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Play!" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

}


?>
```

For one reason or another, `echo $form;` isn't working because it's not showing the registration form.

Could someone explain how to make the content show which is between `$form = <<<EOT` and `</form>`

Comment: Move the final `}` in your code to above `$form = <<<EOT`. Also, `$password == $password2` allows two blank passwords, FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `echo $form;` and the form itself within the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` statement which means they are not going to show until you click submit which you can't because the form isn't there, move the curling brace above the form and that should do it like so:

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

if($password == $password2){
if($email == $email2){
 //All good, carry on the registration.
}else{
 echo "Oh no! We can't sign you up; please double-check your passwords match.<br />";
exit();
}
}else{
echo "Oh no! We can't sign you up; please double-check your emails match.<br /><br />";
}

}

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Play!" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

 ?>
```